# Enums and initialising classes

Tags: c++, enums, initialization

I frequently come across this annoying quirk.

Say I have something like

```
enum class Thing {Ex1, Ex2, Ex3}
```

I have an instance of a Thing and want to create a certain class depending on what it is, and it ends up looking like this

```
switch(_thing){
    case Thing::Ex1:
        ptr = new Class1();
        break;

     case Thing::Ex2:
         ptr = new Class2();
         break;

     case Thing::Ex3:
         ptr = new Class3();
         break; 
}
```

And so on. With 10-20 such statements, it just looks very bad. Is this an inevitability, or is there some way to improve this?

Comment: I can immediately think of several workarounds, most of which end up being even more code, but in different places.  Mostly involving making a map of enum->function pointers of some sort or another.

Comment: or `#define PTR_IS_NEW_THING(n) case GLUE(Thing::Ex,n): ptr=new GLUE(Class,n)(); break`

Comment: My first thought was to use templates and template specialization. Something like: `template<Thing> class Foo{...}` `template<> class Foo<Thing::Ex1> {...}` etc...

Comment: apparently I don't understand your question: If you have to do this multiple times in your code, why don't you put it into a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, C++ still doesn't have reflection. You can consider the tried-and-true X macro, if you have multiple places in your code where you'll have to employ the same mapping of values to types:

```
#define CASES \
    X(Thing::Ex1, Class1) \
    X(Thing::Ex2, Class2) \
    X(Thing::Ex3, Class3) \
    // ...
// ...
switch (_thing) {
#define X(v, T) \
    case (v): \
        ptr = new (T)(); \
        break;
    CASES
#undef X
}
// ... do other things with CASES and a different X macro
// ...
#undef CASES
```

Comment: All the answers were useful and informative. I felt that this was the simplest and most straightforward to implement into my existing code structure.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of items gets large, it makes sense to create an association (aka `map`) between the "Things" and factory methods.  This is easy in say Python, but can be a bit of a pain in C++.

```
typedef Baseclass * (*factoryMethod) (void);

// factories contains the association between types and constructors
std::map <std::string, factoryMethod> factories;

// If possible, it's often a good idea to make these methods static members of Baseclass.
Baseclass * factoryMethodA(void)
{
  return new ClassA();
}

Baseclass * factoryMethodB(void)
{
  return new ClassB();
}
// &ct

my_map["A"] = factoryMethodA;
my_map["B"] = factoryMethodB;
// &ct
```

And usage is just...

```
ptr = factories[classname]();
```

If you are using C++11, I you can save a lot of typing with lambdas, to the point that this is a pretty useful programming tool to have in your belt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class BaseClass {
  public:
  virtual void Print() = 0;
};

class ClassA : public BaseClass {
  public:
  void Print() { std::cout << "Hello "; }
};

class ClassB : public BaseClass {
  public:
  void Print() { std::cout << "World!\n"; }
};

typedef BaseClass * (*factoryMethod) (void);

std::map <std::string, factoryMethod> factories = {
  { "a", []()->BaseClass * {return new ClassA(); } },
  { "b", []()->BaseClass * {return new ClassB(); } }
};

int main (void)
{
  BaseClass * foo = factories["a"]();
  BaseClass * bar = factories["b"]();

  foo->Print();
  bar->Print();

  return 0;
}
```

This lets you do some neat tricks, like being able to use things other than enums since you're no longer bound to `switch`.  Also, it lets you handle different logical associations with the same code (comes up in parsers).

**PS** I didn't use enums in the above code, but the idea is the same.  In my experience, whenever I encountered this problem it was easier to associate strings directly with the intended behavior, so I stuck with that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a codegenerator hidden in C++ called [Template Metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming). You may use it to generate factories you want. You may also use Variadic Templates (that is C++11 feature).

I came to following code (I'm a bit lazy to implement correct "last" specialized `createThing`, so I used `void` as terminator):

```
enum class Thing {Ex1, Ex2, Ex3};

class Class1 { virtual void f() {} };
class Class2 : public Class1 {};
class Class3 : public Class2 {};

template <Thing val_, typename Class_> 
struct MPLFactoryPair  {
    static constexpr Thing val = val_;
    using Class = Class_;
};

template<class head, typename... tail> 
struct MPLFactory {
    static Class1* createThing(Thing thing_) {
        if(thing_ == head::val) {
            return new typename head::Class();
        }
        return MPLFactory<tail...>::createThing(thing_);
    }
};

template<typename last> 
struct MPLFactory<last> {
    static Class1* createThing(Thing thing_) {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

using ThingFactory =
    MPLFactory<MPLFactoryPair<Thing::Ex1, Class1>, 
            MPLFactoryPair<Thing::Ex2, Class2>, 
            MPLFactoryPair<Thing::Ex3, Class3>, 
            void>;
```

The main problem with it is that you should hope that compiler will optimize tail call in `createThing`. GCC does that with -O2:

```
<+20>:    test   %eax,%eax
<+22>:    je     0x400a5e <main(int, char**)+238>
<+28>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
<+31>:    je     0x400a83 <main(int, char**)+275>
<+37>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
<+40>:    jne    0x400a77 <main(int, char**)+263>
```

So it came to simple if-else. Not sure if it will generate jump table.

Here is a test code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    volatile Thing thing = Thing::Ex2;
    Class1* ptr = ThingFactory::createThing(thing);

    std::cout << "ptr = " << ptr << std::endl 
            << "<Class2>(ptr) = "  << dynamic_cast<Class2*>(ptr) << std::endl
            << "<Class3>(ptr) = "  << dynamic_cast<Class3*>(ptr) << std::endl
            << std::endl;
}
```

For me it outputs:

```
ptr = 0x214c010
<Class2>(ptr) = 0x214c010
<Class3>(ptr) = 0
```

You may also use [boost::mpl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html), but it is not easy.